# How to plot multiple prediction estimates with prediction intervals (linear regression)

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression, intervals, prediction

I have a data frame that contains the predictions and prediction intervals of two categorical variables (binary) and I would like to plot these in one plot.

Example of the dataframe (df):

```
  block condition response      fit      lwr      upr
1     1    reward yes        3388.629 2089.910 4687.348
2     2    reward yes        3372.682 2074.191 4671.173
....
```

Options are: reward + yes, reward + no, No reward + yes, no reward+ no.

I would like to get this type of graph but the including all the options (so four lines I think):

[image]

I tried to alter the following code but with no succes:

```
library("ggplot2")
p <- ggplot(df, aes(?, ?)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method = lm)
# 3. Add prediction intervals
p + geom_line(aes(y = lwr), color = "red", linetype = "dashed")+
    geom_line(aes(y = upr), color = "red", linetype = "dashed")
```

I would like to use ggplot but I have no idea how I can get all 4 lines in there. Any help would be great!

Comment: If I understand you correctly, from your figure, you want confidence and prediction bands. Confidence banse for your parameters and prediction bands for your predictions. Is this correct?

Comment: you don't have your data in the data frame shown. You need those to plot the points

Comment: No I just want to show the prediction bands, not the confidence intervals.

Comment: I did not include the entire dataframe since it is very big..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plot you have included in your question is of two continuous variable plotted against each other, so you can't use this type of plot for your data. You say that you have two categorical variables, but you actually have three: `block`, `condition` and `response`.

If you are plotting upper, lower and fitted values for two categorical variables, the natural way to do this in ggplot is with `geom_errorbar`, with one of your categorical variables on the x axis, and another represented by the color of the bars, which are "dodged" at each x axis position so they are apart from each other.

You have a couple of options for how you deal with the different blocks. If you have a small number, then you could put each block in its own facet. If you have a large number, you may need to aggregate your data to average out the blocks.

The two rows of the data frame you provided aren't sufficient to say which of these would be better, so let's make up a similar data set. Here we will assume there are 4 blocks:

```r
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(block     = rep(1:4, 4), 
                 condition = rep(rep(c("reward", "no reward"), each = 4), 2),
                 response  = rep(c("yes", "no"), each = 8),
                 fit       = rep(c(3400, 3200, 3300, 2900), each = 4) + 
                             rnorm(16, 0, 10),
                 lwr       = rep(c(2080, 1900, 2000, 1600), each = 4) + 
                             rnorm(16, 0, 10),
                 upr       = rep(c(4700, 4500, 4600, 4200), each = 4) + 
                             rnorm(16, 0, 10))

df
#>    block condition response      fit      lwr      upr
#> 1      1    reward      yes 3393.735 2079.838 4703.877
#> 2      2    reward      yes 3401.836 2089.438 4699.462
#> 3      3    reward      yes 3391.644 2088.212 4686.229
#> 4      4    reward      yes 3415.953 2085.939 4695.850
#> 5      1 no reward      yes 3203.295 1909.190 4496.057
#> 6      2 no reward      yes 3191.795 1907.821 4499.407
#> 7      3 no reward      yes 3204.874 1900.746 4511.000
#> 8      4 no reward      yes 3207.383 1880.106 4507.632
#> 9      1    reward       no 3305.758 2006.198 4598.355
#> 10     2    reward       no 3296.946 1999.439 4597.466
#> 11     3    reward       no 3315.118 1998.442 4606.970
#> 12     4    reward       no 3303.898 1985.292 4605.567
#> 13     1 no reward       no 2893.788 1595.218 4193.112
#> 14     2 no reward       no 2877.853 1604.179 4192.925
#> 15     3 no reward       no 2911.249 1613.587 4203.646
#> 16     4 no reward       no 2899.551 1598.972 4207.685
```

So we have the same column names and order as your own data, and broadly similar values for the numeric columns.

The obvious way to plot this is ggplot would be:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(within(df, block <- paste("Block", block)),
       aes(condition, fit, color = response, group = response)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(min = lwr, max = upr), size = 1.5, 
                width = 0.25, position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.25), color = "black") +
  facet_wrap(.~block, nrow = 2) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

If you wanted to aggregate the blocks, you could obtain a single panel with:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(condition, response) %>%
  summarise(across(c("fit", "lwr", "upr"), mean)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(condition, fit, color = response, group = response)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(min = lwr, max = upr), size = 1.5, 
                width = 0.25, position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.25), color = "black") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

---

**Edit**

Another alternative is to plot the blocks on the x axis and facet by `condition`:

```r
ggplot(within(df, block <- paste("Block", block)),
       aes(block, fit, color = response, group = response)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(min = lwr, max = upr), size = 1.5, 
                width = 0.25, position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.25), color = "black") +
  facet_grid(condition~.) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Allan, and I indeed forgot about the block variable. there are 14 different blocks and I would also like to visualize the effect of block. Is it possible to somehow do this without plotting 14 different plots?

Comment: Because if I would use the last plot that you suggested I would lose the information from the block effect, since it's aggregated. Is that correct?

Comment: @Eggplant yes, as I showed at the end of the question, you could aggregate the blocks together, though doing so loses some information. The other option would be to facet by condition and put block on the x axis

Comment: Yes putting block on the X-axis would be the best solution! I altered the code like this:
`df %>%
  group_by(condition, response, block) %>%
  summarise(across(c("fit", "lwr", "upr"), mean)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(block, fit, color = condition, group = response)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(min = lwr, max = upr), size = 1.5, 
                width = 0.25, position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.25), color = "black") +
  theme_bw()`

I think it looks very good! (unless you are going to say that I did something horribly wrong in the code :') )